# cgi-bin not executing in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, perl, shell, cgi

i have the below code for ajax call

Here i have script file called site_config to execute.   url: 'cgi-bin/site_config',

But its not executing. what is cgi-bin? and is i need to create a folder called cgi-bin and keep site_config file ?? Can some one please say

```
    $(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    /*ajax call to add status*/
      var formData = $("form").serialize();             
      $.ajax({
        url: 'cgi-bin/site_config',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;           

        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);  
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
    },
        failure: function () {
          alert("Ajax request failed!!!");
        },error: function () {
          alert("Ajax request failed to update site survey!!!");
        }
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is cgi-bin?

It is the traditional name of the directory where CGI executables are kept. This is so that the server can be configured to execute things in that directory and not elsewhere.

> and is i need to create a folder called cgi-bin and keep site_config file ??

You will need to:

1. create the directory.
2. put the script in it.
3. ensure that any dependancies the script has are met.
4. ensure the shebang line is pointing to the correct location of perl (assuming the `perl` tag on the question means it is a Perl CGI program)
5. configure your server to execute scripts in the `cgi-bin` directory